# Can I recognize the faces of people around the world?

Tags: legal, facial-recognition, digital-rights

I created a system where every moment takes photos of the face of who is in the vision of the camera. Initially I took 500 photos of me, to recognize its creator. This takes approximately 20 seconds.

Then every moment he recognizes faces and if it is me, he knows that his creator is present. Any different face, it creates a dataset with a different name and starts taking up to 500 photos to also recognize these faces.

When I say a certain command, it returns all faces I have found that have no ID.

I'm looking for ways to capture the images through some camera that I can carry while walking on the street and in public places.

The problem is that there would be several faces to name. I'm partially solving this problem by trying to recognize these people in social networks. I check the region where the photo was taken and try to find people who have checked in or liked the area on Facebook. But anyway, this is not the big problem, although it is looking for more effective solutions.

> My big problem is: Can I do this? Do I have this right? Can I record a
>   robber robbery and recognize his face in other places? Record an
>   aggression, an act of prejudice and things like that?

The main purpose would be this, but could also be used for other purposes. My fear is being arrested for doing this. Both because he would be taking pictures of people without his consent.

ps: I'm thinking of having a camera in the palm of my hand. It would be a micro camera (I'm trying to find the product on the Internet), to be as discreet as possible.

Comment: The right to take pictures of person without his/her consent would be violation of right to privacy. You should check the local laws of every region before doing such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it might be a helpful place to start:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Street_View_privacy_concerns

The wiki is well cited, so should lead to some useful tidbits.  They break it down by continent and country.

Seems like a parallel to what you're doing, although, if you're not making your data public, I doubt you'll be facing the same privacy issues.

Also relevant would be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_of_privacy

> Examples of places where a person has a reasonable expectation of privacy are a person's residence or hotel room and public places which have been specifically provided by businesses or the public sector in order to ensure privacy, such as public restrooms...
>
> In general, one cannot have a reasonable expectation of privacy in things held out to the public.

My understanding is that there is no expectation of privacy in public places where you'd be capturing the images.

Comment: Thank you very much, this material will help me. Anyway, I'm going to consult a lawyer to be well-guarded.

Comment: @GuilhermeIA   Consulting with an attorney is definitely a good idea--most attorneys will do the initial consult for free. I'm facing different potential issues with my own venture, but early legal consults were critical in forming the long-term strategy and business plan.